# Cannot use array with GCC

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, eclipse-cdt

I'm compiling with GCC 4.8.4 on Linux ( with -std=c++0x -fPIC ).

I want to use a defined by me array but I am getting this error:

```
class value 
{
    public:
    typedef std::vector<value> array;
    typedef std::map<std::string, value> object;
    protected:
        int type_;
        union 
        {
            ...
            array* array_;
        };

    typedef value::array array;
}

class ErrorMessage
{
    array my_array;
}
```

Compiling Error:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.8/array:81:12: note:                 template<class _Tp, long unsigned int _Nm> struct std::array
 struct array
        ^
../sources/ErrorMessage.h:290:2: error: ‘array’ does not name a type
array my_array;
```

There is a way to fix this ? ( With GCC 4.4.7 it's working )

Thank you.

Comment: You don't declare a type for it or size. An array of what? Cows? chars? Airplanes?

Comment: You seem to be using [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) which is a *templated* structure. You need to provide the template arguments.

Comment: I think OP might've forgotten the *one line* that makes the question make more sense before the edit.

Comment: What is `value::`? Anyway you should probably import the name with `using namespace::theNameToUse`, rather than `typedef`ing.

Comment: `Seems to be a bug in the array implementation.` Yes, it is definitely not your mistake, but mistake of hundreds of expert C++  developers that implemented standard library.

Comment: I added more with the types

Comment: Post entire code. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Do you have #include `<array>`? `using namespace std;`?

Comment: Yes, the std namespace it's used. <array> is not needed.

Comment: `class value { public: typedef std::vector<value> array; /* ... */ } typedef value::array array;` ..... **what**. are you deliberately trying to confuse readers with these layers and layers of unnecessary obfuscations, counter to all reasonable intuition?

Comment: Where are these statements written? In `main()`? In some other function? Outside any function? Where is the rest of the code?

Comment: @underscore_d I added the classes in which are used.

Comment: You pasted all the lines of output except for the one that matters!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `<array>` got indirectly included from somewhere and you made the mistake of `using namespace std`, "array" in `ErrorMessage` refers to that name in the `std` namespace.
That is a class template, not a type - hence the error message.

Outside of `value`, its `array` is called `value::array`.
(The `typedef value::array array` in `value` is pointless; the name `array` still only exists in the class scope. You may as well have written `typedef array array;`.)

Write

```
class ErrorMessage
{
    value::array my_array;
};
```

In addition, don't reuse standard names. It confuses everyone.

Comment: You beat me to it. Can't emphasise the last line enough.